# What is the use of multiple dimensions in the work group size of a compute shader?

Tags: opengl, opencl, compute-shader, workgroup

Compute shaders require a work group count when being dispatched. This has to be supplied in 3 dimensions. The same goes for the work group size specified in the compute shader itself.

Function to dispatch a compute shader in OpenGl:   [`glDispatchCompute`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glDispatchCompute).

Question:

- why are there 3 dimensions?
- why not pass 1 big number?
- how do the 3 dimensions result in an actual number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are computations that are inherently 2 or 3 dimensional. And there are computations that are inherently 1 dimensional. *Someone* is going to be inconvenienced. Either the multidimensional users will have to take a 1D index and turn it into 2/3D indices, or the single dimensional users may have to take a 2/3D index and compact it to 1D.

Of course, note the difference between "will" and "may". Single dimension users only need to recognize the Y or Z dimensions if the limitations of the implementation on the X dimension of the dispatch command is too small to run enough invocations. Given that all implementations must provide at least 65535 work groups for each dimension, that covers a lot of ground.

So while the multidimensional nature of compute operations may inconvenience single-dimension work, there's plenty of single-dimension work that *doesn't* get inconvenienced. So "may" is preferable to "will".

> how do the 3 dimensions result in an actual number?

Assuming you need to use the Y and Z corrdinates in your single-dimensional compute operation at all (and you rarely do), there are numerous ways to do it. They only vary with regard to the order of the different dimensions. The following way uses the `gl_LocalInvocationIndex` ordering.

If you need to get an index for a particular work group, that's easy enough:

```
uint WorkGroupIndex = dot(gl_WorkGroupID, uvec3(1, gl_NumWorkGroups.x, gl_NumWorkGroups.x * gl_NumWorkGroups.y));
```

If you need to get an index for each invocation within the entire dispatch call, take `WorkGroupIndex` above and do this:

```
uint UniqueIndex = (WorkGroupIndex * gl_WorkGroupSize.x * gl_WorkGroupSize.y * gl_WorkGroupSize.z) + gl_LocalInvocationIndex;
```

Comment: As a comment; graphics cards historically were designed to store and process 2D textures - the buffer allocation limits being rather smallish. Curiously, when using 3D buffers, the same limits are used for each dimension (atleast on NV cards), meaning that a 3D buffer can store much larger amounts of data, and obviously you can recode any indexing into your personal interpretation of the data dimensionality.

Comment: Great answer. I would add that another benefit of 2D workgroups is that they are usually nearby each other which creates spatial locality which is great for texture caches, whereas a simple 1D to 2D conversion might not produce that. So that work is done for you, and typically aligned well with what the hardware would like to see.

Comment: This is what I'm wondering about, is it really just syntactic sugar? Or are there some implications as to how the workload is distributed on hardware units?

Comment: @The19thFighter: A particular implementation may have a certain way of assigning work groups or items in multidimensional cases, but the standard provides no guarantees. So you can't rely on it, not even on future driver releases of the same hardware.